# Aligning a list (whose elements are aligned left) to the right of the page

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I want to align an ordinary list (bullets on the left) to the right side of the page.  That is, the longest element of the list should be aligned with the right, and the rest of the list should be aligned ordinarily with the list.  Here is a sketch in case it is unclear what I am asking: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHz0Q.jpg

I have read this
([how to right-align on a page a block of multi-lined text which is itself left-aligned within the block?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82761/how-to-right-align-on-a-page-a-block-of-multi-lined-text-which-is-itself-left-al)), and it's exactly what I want, but I cannot find the width of the item including the bullet point.  Any ideas?

EDIT: I should also add that I am using the following commands with the list environment: I am using the following commands with itemize: \begin{itemize}[wide, leftmargin=*, labelsep = 0.75em, align=center].

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easiest to measure the width of your own fake itemize environment. Here you can define a `newcommand` to replace the original `item` and measure the longest item using `\widthof` from the `calc` package. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\ritem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}

\null\hfill\parbox{\widthof{\ritem Some company that has a long name}}{%
\ritem Office 123\par   
\ritem Some building \par  
\ritem Some company that has a long name\par
\ritem Some city, some zip 12345\par
\ritem Some country
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another simpler option is to use a `tabular` to avoid the calculation all together.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\ritem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}

\null\hfill%
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
\ritem Office 123 \\   
\ritem Some building \\  
\ritem Some company that has a long name \\
\ritem Some city, some zip 12345 \\
\ritem Some country
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT:**

Here is the solution with the specifications of itemize provided. BTW, I removed the `align = center`, there is no such option.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{enumitem,calc}
\begin{document}

\null\hfill%
\parbox{\widthof{\textbullet\hspace{.75em}Some company that has a long name}}{%
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, labelsep = 0.75em]
\item Office 123    
\item Some building  
\item Some company that has a long name 
\item Some city, some zip 12345 
\item Some country
\end{itemize}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you!  I will mark this as correct soon, but I have a followup question (and will edit the original post): I am using the following commands with itemize:

\begin{itemize}[wide, leftmargin=*, labelsep = 0.75em, align=center].

Is there a way to account for this with your method?  Thank you.

Comment: @user127496: I provided a solution with your exact itemize specifications.

Comment: Oh my god I'm so happy I found this! It's saved me so many hacky solutions! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A solution with package `listliketab`, which emulates an `itemize` environment within a `tabular`. I defined a new `tabitemise` environment, and `\tabitem` commands, which you can use as `itemize` and `item`. Contents of each item has to be one-lined.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{listliketab}
\newcommand{\tabitem} {\textbullet & }
\newenvironment{tabitemise}{
\par\storestyleof{itemize}
\listliketab
\tabular[t]{@{}Ll@{}}%
}{%
\endtabular\endlistliketab
}

\begin{document}

Some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text.

\raggedleft
\begin{tabitemise}
  \tabitem First item.\\
  \tabitem A longer second item\\
  \tabitem A much longer, last, not least, item
\end{tabitemise}

\end{document}
```

[image]